# How to avoid using instanceof in this "visitor" pattern?

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

There are multiple Controller types which implement zero, one or many interfaces such as Updateable and Publishable

```
public class Controller {
    private void doSomeProcessing() {
        //do some processing
    }
}
public class ArticleController extends Controller implements Publishable {
    public void publish() {
        this.doSomeProcessing();
        //TODO: actually publish article
    }
}
public class HeadlineController extends Controller implements Publishable, Updateable {
    public void publish() {
        this.doSomeProcessing();
        //TODO: actually publish headline
    }
    public void update() {
        this.doSomeProcessing();
        //TODO: actually update headline
    }
}
```

Some tasks in the implementation of these interfaces might contain code that is common to many or all Controller types, yet also some code that is unique to that one Controller type. Instead of having doSomeProcessing() in all of their implementations of Updateable (duplicate code), there can be a singleton overseer called Visitor (maybe not correct) that does all the updating and also calls the Controller's update.

```
public void update(Controller c) {
    if (c instanceof Updateable) {
        c.doSomeProcessing();
        ((Updateable)c).update(); //updateable code specific to this controller
    }
}
```

Avoiding instanceof requires class casting which is also bad:

```
public void update(Updateable c) {
        ((Controller)c).doSomeProcessing();
        c.update(); //updateable code specific to this controller
}
```

Note that instanceof in this case isn't as "bad" as most examples of "bad" usages of instanceof. That's because instead of acting like a switch statement, it's only 1 check to see whether or not it's legal to perform the method. Still, it seems wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Can controller implement the interfaces as a no op (or less likely an abstract method), and derived classes which actually need the contracts to be implemented, override Controllers implementations? Then all derived types of Controller would have .publish, and .update, and only those with an override actually do anything.

Comment: The two aren't equivalent.  The second requires that the caller choose to invoke `update` or not, based on whether `c` is Updateable.  In other words, it merely pushes the work (`instanceof`) off on the caller.

Comment: (Don't believe those who tell you that `instanceof` and cast are evil.  They can be abused, but so can just about any programming construct.)